# Can't change height of Polymer paper-item

Tags: html, polymer, material-design

I have a website up at http://adueppen.github.io/mockup.html but I am unable to increase the height of the paper-items in the list. I have used "height:" in css, putting an invisible icon in, and padding the label, but it still won't work. Does anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Height for paper-item's is defined in https://github.com/Polymer/paper-item/blob/master/paper-item.css as:

```
html /deep/ paper-item {
  ...
  height: 48px;
  ...
}
```

So you'll need to either override that rule OR create a more specific rule. For instance you could add a css class to your paper-items that defines the height you want. Example:

```
<paper-item class="myitem" label="Item 1"></paper-item>

.myitem {
  height:100px;
}
```